# Библиотеки для визуализация алгоритмов сортировки в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, поиск-библиотек

Посмотрел на ютубе видео с визуализацией алгоритмов сортировки и решил сделать что-то подобное на Питоне, но с большой настройкой параметров, например, я хотел бы замедлять время сортировки (чтобы было видно работу алгоритма в замедленном времени), хотел бы менять цвет элемента(ов), который мы переставляем.

Возможно, я не прав, но средств matplotlib для этого не достаточно, так что хотел бы узнать как мою идею можно ещё реализовать? Какие библиотеки можно использовать?

Вот пример того, как я хотел бы сделать:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg&t=1s

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста ваш пример.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у кого-то возник такой же вопрос, то я порекомендую бибилиотку pygame. Она вообще для создания игр, но отлично подходит для визуализации любых алгоритмов сортировки. Пример сортировки пузырьком.

```
import pygame
from random import randint

def swap(list, i, j):
    list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]
    return list

def buble_sort(list, i):
    if list[i-1] > list[i]:
        list = swap(list, i-1, i)
    return list

pygame.init()
screen_width, screen_height = 1600, 900
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
y = screen_height
fps = 10
n = 10#4 #length of list
x0 = 1
xn = screen_height
distance = screen_width/n
width = distance - 1
list = [randint(1, screen_height) for p in range(0, n)]
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

j = 1

while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            run = False

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for i in range(len(list)):
        if i == j - 1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, pygame.Rect(i * distance, y, width, -list[i]))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, pygame.Rect(i * distance, y, width, -list[i]))

    list = buble_sort(list, j)
    j += 1
    if j == len(list):
        j = 1
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: а как запускать его?
scwjbdwjbdwbf
bcjwbjc

Comment: https://github.com/KirillGordievich/Bubble_Sort_Visualization

Comment: Давно не заходил на сайт, поэтому не отвечал.